# Apache2 Como entrar por dominio y no la ip?

Tags: apache, debian

Tengo un servidor apache en un vps, y en la carpeta /ruta/apache2/sites-available tengo la config de mi pagina web.

Como puedo hacer para no tener que entrar por la ip? Tengo que comprar un dominio?

Ej actual: http://ipdelservidor/ --> http://nombredeldominio.com

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es ningún problema de programación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende de donde compres el dominio, si tienes un DNS interno etc. La configuración mas básica y general que se te puede sugerir es una vez compres el dominio debes editar la Zona DNS, agregar un record A, colocando en **name** o host el valor www y como valor colocas la IP publica de tu servidor.

De modo que si compras el dominio marc.com al agregar el record A mencionado tendrás www.marc.com que se resuelve a tu IP publica.

Dependiendo de en que empresa has comprado pues ellos pondrán a tu disposicin alguna herramienta o interfaz desde donde puedas gestionar tu dominio por ejemplo así puedes hacerlo en [godaddy](https://es.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238), o en [CPanel](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/updating-an-a-record-in-cpanel/)

Comment: Muchas, gracias lo he probado y funciona :)

Comment: @marc me puedes ayudar con lo mismo por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Depende del SO del servidor, por ejemplo

**Debian:**

Debes editar este fichero: `/$ sudo vi /etc/hosts`

[image: apache]

Aquí pones la ip y al lado el nombre con el cual quieres acceder.

Te dejo la fuente de donde he sacado la información. **[Fuente](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.hostname-name-service.html)**

[debian](/questions/tagged/debian)[apache](/questions/tagged/apache)

Comment: Pero no entiendo una cosa, imagina que tengo un dominio que se llama prueba1.com por poner un ejemplo, si yo intento acceder tendre que tener el dominio comprado no? No tengo que editar nada de DNS?

Comment: Si quieres tener-lo a producción sí, deberás comprar un dominio. Lo que te enseño yo es para entrar desde local o en pc's en la misma red.

Comment: Claro yo tengo el vps contratado y me interesaría tener un dominio propio. Sabes como se haría? Teniendo en cuenta que ya tengo comprado el dominio.

Comment: Esto creo que depende del proveedor que tengas