# Se pueden tener dos apaches a la vez?

Tags: apache2

El apache que instalas desde  powershell de windows y el de xampp. He cambiado los puertos del de xampp pero aún así no funciona. Si es así como podría hacerlo. Es que el localhost no se actualiza en el navegador los cambios que hago y cuando antes lo utilizaba com xampp si

Comment: He buscado en Google tu problema y he tenido varios resultados. [Resultado 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108210/c%C3%B3mo-podr%C3%ADa-tener-dos-servidores-apache-y-balancear-las-conexiones-entre-ellos). [Resultado 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41872/apache2-como-entrar-por-dominio-y-no-la-ip)

Comment: También serviría que mejores tu pregunta ya que carece de imágenes o pruebas de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, lo que causara que tu pregunta sea cerrada.

Comment: al final desinstale el apache de comandos y me descargue xampp me funciona pero no se actualiza la informacion del localhost